# Multiple overlay on mouseover with simple materialize dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, materialize

I'm trying to create a simple dropdown menu with Angualar 4 and Materialize

Here is my issue in picture :

[image]

It's not really clear in the picture but you can see there are two grey overlay one for the `<li>` and one for the `<a>` button inside that is the grey the most visible.

- If you drag the image on something dark you will see it -

The whole `<li>` should be clickable and should be the only one appearing. I don't understand why the `<a>` is appearing and is smaller

```
#dropdown-menu-main {
    width:270px !important;
    z-index:1001;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 2px 10px 0px;
    overflow: visible !important;
}

<div id="dropdown-menu-main" class="dropdown-content card white">

 <ul>
    <li class="blue lighten-1 white-text user-details">
      <app-user-menu></app-user-menu>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/home/map" class="btn-flat waves-effect black-text">
        <i class="material-icons left blue-text">local_shipping</i> Tracking
      </a>
    </li>
 <li>
      <a href="/home/map" class="btn-flat waves-effect black-text">
        <i class="material-icons left blue-text">credit_card</i> Autre item 1
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/ref/other1" class="btn-flat waves-effect black-text">
        <i class="material-icons left blue-text">date_range</i> Autre item 2
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/ref/other2" class="btn-flat waves-effect black-text">
        <i class="material-icons left blue-text">settings</i> Autre item 3
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The background color changes to grey when you hover? Or you just do  that for the demonstration?

Comment: It's a dropdown so when the mouse goes over it the cells are colored in light grey. And yes you don't see it but the mouse should be in the picture it's a screenshot

Comment: Have you tried to make <a> take all the spaces? #dropdown-menu-main > a { width: 100%, height: 100%}

Comment: Same result. I don't understand what I'm missing here, it should be straightforward, a simple dropdown

Comment: You can force the background color of <a> elements  to be the same background color as <li> elements on hover with css.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I found the solution